# Convert string(integer) to date in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have this query at the moment

```
SELECT 
  year_start_1

FROM 
  table1
```

But i need to convert it to date

Currently it outputs just a string  like this `20100731` but I want it to look like this `31/07/2010`

Any ideas

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT convert(varchar,   convert(datetime,'20100731'), 103)
```

for different format: http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: But the source column actually is an integer, not a string

Comment: convert won't seem to work i'm using ASP.net VB and it keeps throwing up an error everytime I try and use convert

Comment: in sql its converting. nothing to worry about VB or C#

Comment: but adding it into my query in my ASPX page it breaks

Answer (score 1):

Convert the column to `varchar`:

```
cast(year_start_1 as varchar(16))
```

Then convert the result to a datetime:

```
convert(datetime, '20100731', 103)
```

Combining the two:

```
select  convert(datetime, cast(year_start_1 as varchar(16)), 103)
from    table1
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT convert(datetime,   convert(varchar, year_start_1))
```